# Using UUID in View_Detail page in Django

Tags: django

I have an app that is working fine, but i just changed the ID to UUIDm and the route no longer work.
I have the following route:

path("documents/uuid:uuid/",views.document_show, name="document_show"),

and the following view:

```
def document_show(request, id):
    student_list = DocumentAttachment.objects.all()
    for student in student_list:
        print("we are printing the list of imaged uploaded :", student.attachment)
    context = {}
    try:
        context["data"] = Document.objects.get(id=id)
    except Document.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Book does not exist')
    return render(request, "documents/show.html", context)
```

With the architecture: `template/documents/show.html`

May I ask what is the right way to setup the routes please?

Comment: path("documents/<uuid:uuid1>/",views.document_show, name="document_show")
You forget to give < > sign

Comment: this one does : ValidationError at /documents/38d3459c-d5dc-40ac-91ba-3e43e4a41b09/
['“<built-in function id>” is not a valid UUID.']

Comment: You are not getting an error like `TypeError: document_show() got an unexpected keyword argument 'uuid'`? did you update your view function as `document_show(request, uuid)`? If you did likely you forgot to update this line `Document.objects.get(id=id)`

Comment: And it works! thank you very much! Can make an answer and I add a point for you ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly as pointed out by [@Boma Anjang](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67386512/using-uuid-in-view-detail-page-in-django#comment119108538_67386512) in their comment you missed the `<>` symbols in your pattern which then should be:

```py
path("documents/<uuid:uuid>/",views.document_show, name="document_show"),
```

Next your view is defined as `document_show(request, id)` this needs to be updated as the captured arguments are passed as keyword arguments to the view and hence need to have the correct name.

Similarly `Document.objects.get(id=id)` also needs to be updated.

Hence your view should be something like:

```py
def document_show(request, uuid):
    student_list = DocumentAttachment.objects.all()
    for student in student_list:
        print("we are printing the list of imaged uploaded :", student.attachment)
    context = {}
    try:
        context["data"] = Document.objects.get(uuid=uuid) # Not sure of the name of your field for the uuid, edit as per the name
    except Document.DoesNotExist:
        raise Http404('Book does not exist')
    return render(request, "documents/show.html", context)
```

Comment: Thank you Abdul, last question please, do you know how to make a link to a a detail_view under the document_show function please ?

Comment: @FrankyDoul Don't know your url patterns, etc. but in the template one generally uses the [url template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#url) and in the view one uses [`reverse` function](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/urlresolvers/#reverse) or `reverse_lazy` (in case the urls might not be loaded yet)